# User Search results not sorted by reputation

Tags: bug, sorting, user-search

The [user search feature](https://stackoverflow.com/users) used to sort users by reputation in the given timeframe both when listing all users and when searching specific user names. This allowed us to find the user with the highest reputation and a specific name, or search for specific high reputation users when we knew their name but not their user ID.

Now, it only appears to sort users by reputation when a search term is not entered, otherwise it is sorted by user ID.

Results without search term:
[image: Image of results without search term]

Results with search term:
[image: Image of results with search term]

We can see from the results in [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111229/type-to-find-users-textbox-doesnt-remember) that it used to work as intended (although the image is old I remember it functioning far more recently):

[image: Historical image of results with search term]

This appears to affect all sites.